# Spark : SQL Context : Creating a data frame from Scala object

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5.2 to create a data frame from scala object using of of the following syntax. My purpose is to create a data for for unit testing.

```scala
class Address (first:String = null, second: String = null, zip: String = null){}
class Person (id: String = null, name: String = null, address: Seq[Address] = null){}
```

---

```scala
def test () = {

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  import sqlContext.implicits._

  val persons = Seq(
    new Person(id = "1", name = "Salim", 
      address = Seq(new Address(first = "1st street"))),
    new Person(name = "Sana",
      address = Seq(new Address(zip = "60088")))
  )

  // The code can't infer schema automatically
  val claimDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(persons, 2),classOf[Person])

  claimDF.printSchema() // This prints "root" not the schema of Person.
}
```

**Instead if I convert the Person and Address to case class then Spark can inherit schema automatically** using the above syntax or using `sc.parallelize(persons, 2).toDF` or using `sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(persons, 2),StructType)`

I can't use case class because it can't hold more than 20 fields and I have a lot of fields in the class. And using StructType causes a lot of inconvenience. Case class is most convenient but can't hold too many properties.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that if your classes extend the [Product trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.6/#scala.Product) and implement its abstract methods it might work. (because of this signature: `createDataFrame[A <: Product](data: Seq[A])`)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the input.

We ultimately migrated to Spark 2.1 with Scala 2.11 which supported a larger case class so this issue got resolved.

For Spark 1.6 and Scala 2.10 I ended up building Row object and Struct type to build a Dataframe.

```
val rows = Seq(Row("data"))
val aRDD = sc.parallelize(rows)
val aDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(aRDD,getSchema())

def getSchema(): StructType= {
    StructType(
        Array(
            StructField("jobNumber", StringType, nullable = true))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes to your code will make printSchema() emit the full structure of your dataframe without using case classes.

Firstly, as Daniel suggested, you need to have your classes extend the [scala.Product](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.6/#scala.Product) trait (painful, but required for the `.toDF` method below):

```
class Address (first:String = null, second: String = null, zip: String = null) extends Product with Serializable
{
  override def canEqual(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[Address]
  override def productArity: Int = 3
  def productElement(n: Int) = n match {
    case 0 => first; case 1 => second; case 2 => zip
  }
}

class Person (id: String = null, name: String = null, address: Seq[Address] = null) extends Product with Serializable
{
  override def canEqual(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[Person]
  override def productArity: Int = 3
  def productElement(n: Int) = n match {
    case 0 => id; case 1 => name; case 2 => address
  }
}
```

Secondly, you should create your dataframe using the .toDF implicit method that is brought into scope with `import sqlContext.implicits._`  rather than using `sqlContext.createDataFrame(..)` like so:

```
val claimDF = sc.parallelize(persons, 2).toDF
```

then claimDF.printSchema() will print:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- first: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- second: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- zip: string (nullable = true)
```

Alternatively, you could use [Scala 2.11.0-M3](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7296) which removes the 22 field limit on case classes.